# How to Set SwRevealview controller as Root view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SwReveal view controller.It is initially set as root view controller. I am using a Login screen when app logged in I remember the user name and next time when the app is opened i set a main screen as Root view controller. But here where my problem starts. When i set main screen as Root view controller SWREVEAL view controller is no longer my root view controller. How to set SWRevealController back to Root view controller in Main screen View did load  method.

Here is how i set main screen as Root view controller

```
TimeTableViewController * time = (TimeTableViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Time"];

navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:time];

self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
   // [self.window setRootViewController:navigation];
   [self.window addSubview:navigation.view];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Here is how my Reveal view controller is set.. its in Main Screen View did load method. But becoz of i changed the root view controller from "SWREVALVIEWCONTROLLER" to "Main screen" view controller the below code doesnt work and doest open up the reveal. Please help

```
LearningSearchController *slideView = [[LearningSearchController alloc]init];
slideView.delegate = self;

[(LearningSearchController *)self.revealViewController.rightViewController setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is Login Screen. Keep SwRevealViewController as rootview controller and for login check in frontview screen. If user is not logged in then present LoginViewController. For example MainScreen is a frontview for SwRevealViewController then in viewdidLoad check user is already logged in or not.